# Probability change of variables with operator instead of function

Tags: probability, operator-theory, change-of-variable

I know that if I have a random variable $X$ with probability density $f_X(x)$ and define $Y=g(X)$, where $g(x)$ is monotonic and bijective, then I can find the probability density of $Y$ with
$$
f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\right|.
$$
This result can be generalized to non-monotonic functions for $Y=g(X)$ and can be extrapolated to multivariate $X$ and $Y$.

But what I have not seen is what to do if $g(x)$ is an operator instead of a function, for example $y=\frac{d}{dz}x$ or for multivariate variables, $\boldsymbol{y}=\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol{x}$.

In the case that the transformation that takes $x\rightarrow y$ is an operator can I still use the regular change of variables formulas? If not is there an equivalent?

Comment: Well the expected value $\mathsf EX=\int x\mathrm dF_X$ could be an example of an operator acting on $X$. In this case the result is a constant. I'm not sure how you would assign a meaning to something like $Y=\partial_x X$.

Comment: Aaron Hentrickson, I guess in my mind I am specifically thinking about vector calculus where I know the probability of some $\boldsymbol{A}$ and I would like to derive the probability for $\boldsymbol{v}=\nabla\times\boldsymbol{A}$ or $\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol{A}$. In these cases it seems reasonable to expect that if I can assign a probability to a vector field, then I would expect that there should be a corresponding probability for the curl or divergence of that field. Perhaps my question only makes sense when thinking about fields?